# find_package(MPI REQUIRED) is not locating the right mpi

Tags: cmake, mpi, find-package

I have `find_package(MPI REQUIRED)` in my CMakeLists.txt. And there are two versions of mpi installed.

1. `/opt/hpcx/ompi/lib`;
2. `/usr/local/mpi/lib`;

Everytime I run `CMake`, it choose `/opt/hpcx/ompi/lib`.

```
-- Found MPI (include: , library: /opt/hpcx/ompi/lib/libmpi.so)
```

What do I need to do to make it locate the one under  `/usr/local/mpi/lib`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the cmake `FindMPI` package, there are various environment variables you can set to force it to find your preferred MPI.

See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindMPI.html

You can set the environment variable `MPI_HOME` or the CMake variable: `-D MPI_HOME=/your/mpi`